# Specify condition and limit for firebase realtime database request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to store some certain information in the firebase realtime database. My database structure looks like this:

```
    {
  "contacts" : {
    "-KdD1f0ecmVXHZ3H3abZ" : {
      "email" : "ksdsd@sdsd.com",
      "first_name" : "John",
      "last_name" : "Smith",
      "organization_id" : 1
    },
    "-KdG4iHEYjInv7ljBhgG" : {
      "email" : "superttest@sds213123d.com",
      "first_name" : "Max1",
      "last_name" : "Rosse13131313l",
      "organization_id" : 1
    },
    "-KdGAZ8Ws6weXWo0essF" : {
      "email" : "superttest@sds213123d.com",
      "first_name" : "Max1",
      "last_name" : "Rosse13131313l",
      "organization_id" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

I need to be able to specify condition like this SQL example:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE organization_id = :id LIMIT :start, :end
```

is there a way to do that in the database using Ruby or at least their REST API?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can be divided into two steps.

Step 1) You have to update rules in firebase Database if not already done.

```
{
  "rules": {
     "read": "auth !=null",
     "write": "auth !null",
     "REPLACE_WITH_ROOT_NODE_NAME": {
       "contacts": {
          "indexOn": ["organization_id"]
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Step 2) To fetch data from firebase Database. The rest API request should be something like this

```
https://app-name.firebaseio.com/REPLACE_WITH_ROOT_NODE_NAME/contacts.json?auth=REPLACE_WITH_DATABASE_PASSWORD&orderBy="organization_id"&equalTo="REPLACE_WITH_ORGANIZATION_ID"&LimitToFirst=N
```