# How to get specific child value from entire database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example, to get all host_city values

[image: For example, to get all host_city values]

Comment: Querying db is given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315302/specify-condition-and-limit-for-firebase-realtime-database-request

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I want. Just in Android :( I'm so confused

Comment: You have to api calls according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference('Apartmani Dzana');
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey()); // -K...
         System.out.println(childSnapshot.child("ap_code").getValue(String.class)); 
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
  };
);
```

It may be useful if you take the [Firebase codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) before continuing on your own app. It will teach you basic data access and many more things about using Firebase, in a more step-by-step way.

Comment: yes, but I have in other nodes ap_code values. For example in Apartmani Basic.. from all of these I should query 'ap_code' :/

Comment: Right now you keep the apartments in multiple lists. A Firebase query executes over a single list. If you want to show the code for all apartments, you should create a list of all apartments.

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseRef.child('Users').addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         // parse the snapshot to your local model
         User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

         // access your desired field
         String name = user.getName();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  };
);
```